# how to show images without passing it to timthumb.php file for resizing

Tags: php, images, timthumb

currently I m showing post image and it's exceprt on my index page of website. Beacuse of this site is slow downs as each image is passed to timthumb.php file. I want to change in code so that image is displayed direct without passing to timthumb.php file for resizing. Is there any way to achieve this??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show the code from you index.php template.

Comment: Is the image in question an *attached* image? Is the image in question the *Post Featured Image*?

Answer (score 1):

add the size to your images sizes using [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) to your theme's functions.php file. eg:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 220, 180 ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall
}
```

then set the image as featured image from the media uploader of the posts :

[image]

then open your index.php and replace the image tag that is calling the `timthumb.php` file for resizing with:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
} else {
    //show default image if none is set
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can we set image size setting in media setting instead of adding add_image_size() in function.php file.??

Comment: Not really since the `add_image_size` has to be fired before the image is uploaded. So out of the box it won't work but with some custom coding you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the image attached to the post:

```
function firstimg($parent){
    global $wpdb;
    $image = wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_parent='.$parent.' AND post_type="attachment" AND post_mime_type LIKE "%image%" ORDER BY menu_order ASC LIMIT 1');

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: I much prefer [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article I wrote on images, image sizes and thumbnails in WordPress: http://theme.fm/2011/08/images-image-sizes-and-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress-1385/

Answer (score 0):

I see someone else has already recommended using `the_post_thumbnail()`, but I wanted to point out that you can use this function *dynamically* to create images of any size.

In your code, just use:

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 150) );
```

This will display the post's thumbnail image at 100px wide by 150px high.

If your image isn't set as the post's thumbnail, you can use `wp_get_attachment_image()` in a similar fashion:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1, array(100, 150) );
```

Just substitute the ID of the attached image for the `1` above, and the width/height you want.  Be sure to use `echo` because the function by default "gets" the image information and returns it ... you need to `echo` it back to the browser.